# Why does Law want to kill Kaido?

Tags: one-piece

Law makes an alliance with Mugiwara to kill one of the Yonko, Kaido of the Beasts. But, why does Law want to kill Kaido?
Is it because Law wants to be one of Yonko?

Comment: He didn't want to kill Kaido, he wanted Doflamingo taken down because of his past. I don't want to spoil everything but if you have read the manga or watch the anime you will understand what I am saying.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per [One Piece Wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Kaido):

> Trafalgar Law sought out an alliance with Monkey D. Luffy and the Straw Hat Pirates allegedly in order to dethrone Kaido. Luffy agreed to the alliance and even declared that he will defeat all four Yonko. Even though Law suggested that their chances of success are only 30%, Luffy remained undeterred. **However, it is later revealed by Law himself that he only formed an alliance with Luffy because he wanted to use the Straw Hats to destroy the factory producing SMILEs to get Kaido angry at Doflamingo and not as a means to dethrone Kaido.**

This was revealed in the last page of chapter 724:

[image]

Comment: You don't need to spoiler tag, when it has already been aired in the cartoons. They are at the rescue of Mansherry atm.

Comment: @Peter Raeves Yeah, I'm on the latest episode myself. I thought that the OP must be in the early 600s because of his question, and hence put the spoiler tag.

Comment: Not sure what the site's actual guidelines are, but unless they specifically state otherwise, I always assume they are up to date with the medium they are asking a question about.

Comment: And if they are not up to date, they are asing because they don't mind spoilers, right?
Why else would they openly ask about?

Comment: Yeah. I won't use spoiler tag for stuff that has already aired then.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true.

Law has a plan to kill(or defeat) Kaido and the reason is the connection between the emeperor and Doflamingo himself(smile's factory).

Sure he wanted to defeat Doflamingo in the process, but the plan against Kaido exist anyways.

Comment: as per wiki that @Ashishgup mentioned, **However, it is later revealed by Law himself that he only formed an alliance with Luffy because he wanted to use the Straw Hats to destroy the factory producing SMILEs to get Kaido angry at Doflamingo and not as a means to dethrone Kaido.** Right now Law on Wano just because to complete the promise that he make an alliance with Luffy to defeated Kaido, not because he's intentionally to kill Kaido.

Answer (score -1):

It's true that Law wanted to take down Doflamingo - but he ALSO want to take down Kaido. Chapter 667:

> If you want to survive in the New World, there are only two ways to go about it. Either you swear allegiance to one of the Yonkou... or you do battle with them.

[image]

Comment: Any explanation why I got a downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote myself, but I suppose it is because your answer is considered incorrect. Law only said that to get Luffy to join him. He only really wanted to kill Doffy to avenge Corazon. He didn't have any interest in Kaidou. As said in the other answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if he has "no interest". Is defeating Doflamingo his one and only goal in life? If yes, then he will stop being a pirate now. But if he still will be a pirate, then he has to decide if he should take down one of the Yonkou or to swear allegiance to them - and I beliebe Law would decide to fight against a Yonkou.

Comment: Well Law did say `13 years I have lived on, all for the day I would take down Doflamingo` in chapter 783. Later in chapter 798 he said `I've lived for the day I could take Doflamingo's head, in Corazon's stead`. He fulfilled his goal in life, that doesn't mean he should stop living though. He can still be a pirate, he can still go after Kaidou, but his goal for going to Dressrosa was Doflamingo and not Kaidou.

Comment: That's all true, but the originally question was NOT: _"Why did he go to Dressrosa?"_ but _"What's the reason to go after Kaidou?"_. As you say by yourself: He can **still** go after Kaidou, and I gave an answer why he can **still** go after Kaidou (even if this was not his main goal, there _is_ a reason to go after him). That's how I understand the question: Asking for a reason to go after Kaidou.